# How to scale target webpage linked with parse

Tags: webview, scale, zooming, android-websettings

I have a program with a button to login via `GET` method, it works perfectly, but when I log in, the form appears zoomed out far and little. I wanted to know if there is any option with `WebSettings.ZoomDensity`, or `WebView` class, to scale the form size to the screen of the device.

The button code is this:

```
   public void IniciSessio_BTN_Click(View Target) {
            if (U.getText().length() <= 0)
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Username", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else if (K.getText().length() <= 0)
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else
            {
                DadesUsuari = U.getText().toString();
                DadesClau = K.getText().toString();
                DadesDesar = Desar_CB.isChecked();

                Uri uri = Uri.parse( "http://www.mypage.com/?U="+U.getText().toString()+"&K="+K.getText().toString() );
                startActivity( new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri ) );
    }
}
```

I tryed to do this:

```
webview.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.CLOSE);
```

But it doesn't works. It make me to create the WebView class and it crashes the app.

Also tryed this:

```
private WebView Navegador = null;

            Navegador = new WebView(this);
            Navegador.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Navegador.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
            Navegador.setInitialScale(73);

            Uri uri = Uri.parse( "http://stats.serhstourism.com/?U="+U.getText().toString()+"&K="+K.getText().toString() );
        startActivity( new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri ) );

            WebSettings webSettings = Navegador.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [this article](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/targeting.html).

I think you have to set the viewport size in your html. Something like this ...

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=100px, height:100px" />
```

Obviously you're going to have to change the pixel values. For more information how this works look at the article mentioned above.

Comment: Yep, I've tried that before. but I can't modify the HTML so I have to do it from the app